# Where is the code of containerd/runc in docker-ce?

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to debug docker (including everything, *docker, dockerd, containerd, runc*), and have cloned source code from *github/docker/docker-ce*.

Now I can locate the source code of:

- **docker** (docker-cli): at components/cli
- **dockerd**: at components/engine/daemon

in repo of docker-ce and successfully `make` them.

But I cannot find the code of *containerd* and *runc* in docker-ce repo, while there are binaries of them when `make` command is triggered.

So where the binaries come from?

I know there are repos of *containerd* and *runc*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own findings from a quick scan. The [Makefile for components/engine](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/1cad3b08d5e4fc6068d34e72aa10df4a78189d13/components/engine/Makefile) includes various steps, including a docker build.

The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/1cad3b08d5e4fc6068d34e72aa10df4a78189d13/components/engine/Dockerfile) includes sections for containerd and runc:

```
FROM base AS containerd
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y btrfs-tools
ENV INSTALL_BINARY_NAME=containerd
COPY hack/dockerfile/install/install.sh ./install.sh
COPY hack/dockerfile/install/$INSTALL_BINARY_NAME.installer ./
RUN PREFIX=/build/ ./install.sh $INSTALL_BINARY_NAME

FROM runtime-dev AS runc
ENV INSTALL_BINARY_NAME=runc
COPY hack/dockerfile/install/install.sh ./install.sh
COPY hack/dockerfile/install/$INSTALL_BINARY_NAME.installer ./
RUN PREFIX=/build/ ./install.sh $INSTALL_BINARY_NAME
```

Then in the hack folder for the dockerfile, there are scripts to install [containerd](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/1cad3b08d5e4fc6068d34e72aa10df4a78189d13/components/engine/hack/dockerfile/install/containerd.installer) and [runc](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/1cad3b08d5e4fc6068d34e72aa10df4a78189d13/components/engine/hack/dockerfile/install/runc.installer).

These scripts clone the repo and checkout specific commits from [containerd](https://github.com/containerd/containerd) and [runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc)'s upstream repos.